# is it possible to use/connect AWS Cognito user pool to AWS SFTP Server access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How can I configure my AWS-SFTP-SERVER/AWS-COGNITO-USER-POOL to provide access all existing and new users of pool to access AWS SFTP Server...

Answer (score 0):

so finally able to find some good work after lot of research...

AWS SFTP server can be authenticated using username/password which will be created in Cognito user pool but AWS does not provide inbuilt this functionality. we need to Create API gate way for the same.

SFTP -> Custom Identity Provider -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> Cognito user pool

Soon I will post Lambda code for the same..

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work and debugging, I finally figured out the secret sauce.  I'm gonna break it down here as fast as I can.  So first, here was my use case.

1. AWS SFTP using passwords instead of ssh keys
2. users' home directory must be chrooted
3. Ability of users to share a directory with others
4. no new API gateway to secure and manage

Here is how I solved it:

1. setup sftp server with "Use AWS Lambda to connect your identity provider".  This is important as it means you don't have to setup api gateway
2. create a cognito userpool and make sure you have a cutom attribute called HOME_DIR.  Don't forget to set the field as readable in the app integration section or it won't be in the IdToken field.  When you create the userpool make sure you don't require hashsecret or your lambda will not be able to AdminInititateAuth
3. create a Role that can give the transfer service the ability to do S3 stuff (figure 1)
4. write a lambda call sftp_auth.  Note the importance is the payload structure which is as follows:

```json
 {
        Role: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SFTPS3Role", // policy attached to this role is defined in figure 2
        HomeDirectoryDetails: JSON.stringify([{Entry: "/", Target: "/mybucket/sftp/username"}]), // sets the virtual home directory
        HomeDirectoryType: "LOGICAL", // forces the chrooting
        Password: "xxxx" // Not sure this one is strictly necessary
    }
```

Here is figure 2:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

finally here is the source for the lambda:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
/**
 * sample payload:
 * {
    "username": "username",
    "sourceIp": "192.168.1.1",
    "protocol": "SFTP",
    "serverId": "s-12345679012",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

 */
const HOME_DIR_ATTR = "custom:HOME_DIR";
export const handler = async(event) => {
        console.log(`event body = ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
        
        let payload = event; // TODO: consider making event more flexible
       
        let USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID = "xxxclientidxxx"; 
        let USER_POOL_ID = "xxxxpoolidxxxx"; 
        AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
     
            

        const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        let params = {
            AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
            ClientId: USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID, // From Cognito dashboard
            UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
            AuthParameters: {
              USERNAME: payload.username,
              PASSWORD: payload.password
            }
          };

        const jwtContainer = await cognito.adminInitiateAuth(params).promise();
        
        console.log(`jwtContainer = ${JSON.stringify(jwtContainer)}`);
        let authResult = jwtContainer["AuthenticationResult"];
        console.log(`${JSON.stringify(authResult)}`);
        let token = authResult["IdToken"];
        console.log("token = "+token);
       
        let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log("decoded = "+JSON.stringify(decoded));
        console.log("homedir = "+decoded[HOME_DIR_ATTR]);  
        

    
    let response = {
        Role: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SFTPS3Role",
        HomeDirectoryDetails: JSON.stringify([{Entry: "/", Target: decoded[HOME_DIR_ATTR]}]),
        HomeDirectoryType: "LOGICAL",
        Password: payload.password
    };
    return response;
};
```

Other notes: my lambda code relies on 2 layers each from public npm packages:  aws-sdk (provides cognito client) and jwt-decode (provides a library to decode the id token returned after logging in using the cognito client without having to verify the idtoken a second time).  Make sure you have those 2 layers or none of this works.